# Saving the results as LUT

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np, itertools

x1 = np.linspace(0.1, 3.5, 3)
x2 = np.arange(5, 24, 3)
x3 = np.arange(50.9, 91.5, 3)

def calculate(x1,x2,x3):
    res = x1**5+x2*x1+x3
    return res


products = list(itertools.product(x1,x2,x3))

results = [calculate(a,b,c) for a,b,c in products]
```

I have to save the results as look up tables for future use.
In my real case, the file is going to be very large around 1GB. So I need faster way of reading that file later.
**What is the best way and file format to save it to access in future?**

```
outputs = np.column_stack((products,results))
np.savetxt('test.out',outputs, delimiter = ',')
```

My future use as follows:

```
#given_x1,given_x2,given_x3 = 0.2, 8, 60
#open the look up table
#read the neighbouring two values for the given values
#linearly interpolate between two values for the results.
```

Comment: So is this a 1-D array? You could load this into a numpy array and then just write it out using `np.savetxt`

Comment: In my real case, the file is going to be very large around 1GB. It is okay to read that data with text file later.

Comment: Should be, have to go now but if this question is still unanswered I'll have a crack in an hours time

Comment: @EdChum Are you there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd construct a 1-D array from the list comprehension and save this out:

```
In [37]:

a = np.array([calculate(a,b,c) for a,b,c in products])
np.savetxt(r'c:\data\lut.txt', a)
In [39]:

b = np.loadtxt(r'c:\data\lut.txt')
np.all(a==b)
Out[39]:
True
```